# How to convert negative values to positive values before they are calculated in a generator expression with a slice?

Tags: python, json

The format of my JSON is as follows:

```
[
  ...
  {'minute': 87, 'value': -100},
  {'minute': 88, 'value': 4},
  {'minute': 89, 'value': -85},
  {'minute': 90, 'value': 4},
  {'minute': 90.5, 'value': 15}
]
```

To calculate the last 5 values I use:

```
response2 = requests.get(url2, headers=headers).json()
graphs = response2['graphPoints']

    sum(d["value"] for d in graphs["graphPoints"][-5:])
```

But I would like to convert these negative values to positive before they are calculated.

How I could do this in a simple or fast way without having to work with a list such as `list_of_values = []` and then create a looping `for value in list_of_values:` to convert each value?

The current result is `-100+4-85+4+15 = -162`

The expected result is `100+4+85+4+15 = 208`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `abs` function in your comprehension list:

```py
sum(abs(d["value"]) for d in graphs["graphPoints"][-5:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
sum(abs(d["value"]) for d in graphs["graphPoints"][-5:])
```

Comment: Hi @KarolAdamiak I apologize but I will have to mark the other guy's answer as a solution, he ended up posting a few seconds earlier, so as a rule the score should be given to him. But I appreciate his help!